# Upgrading to Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, windows-8

I really like the open source ideology and am thinking of installing ubuntu. Currently I'm using windows 8 but my computer was originally windows 7. Much of the software I currently have on my computer I would need to keep. Is this possible? I could do with keeping microsoft office (I know ubuntu supports office files but I would like to be able to create files in the office format for work reasons). I also need to do .net framework programming. I know you can set up a virtual machine to do this but is it difficult and what kind of problems do people often encounter doing this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no way to upgrade from any version of Windows to Ubuntu. You'll have to do a clean install, and possibly dual boot. You also can not keep the software, as software for Windows insn't directly compatible with Ubuntu. That's life, make your choice.

Comment: This is could be the biggest duplicate in the history of the world.

Comment: Well there are solutions, dual boot (keep windows, and have Ubuntu on one side). that's my recomendation. Search for it on the site. just close the question.
@MikeWhatever heard of wine? dual boot and keep windows?

Comment: To some extend you can manage windows applications via Wine.